# Click event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, dom-events

I'm working on an Electron-based application, and I don't have much experience with it or JavaScript or Node.js. Currently, I just want to close a window by a click on a button.

```
close.addEventListener('click', function () {
    ipc.send('close-main-window')
})
```

This totally works! I am just confused with why it works. From what I understand, the first argument in `addEventListener` is just any arbitrary string. However, I don't specifically write anything to handle a 'click'. This should mean it's built in functionality, I think. Is this part of JavaScript, Node.js, or Electron? And where in the documentation can I find a list of built in events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has the function `addEventListener` which adds an event listener (surprise, surprise) to an element. The element in which the listener is applied to now listens for an event, a string passed into the function (in this case click). Once the event is triggered (in this case when a user clicks on the element), it will execute the callback, which is the function you declared. So, consider this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("hello!");
});
```

This will log `hello` every time `element` is clicked.

You can read more at the [Mozilla's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). [Here's](http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php) a list of all the available events.

Comment: Thanks! Are these events just strings? And if so, isn't that sort of bad design? Wouldn't it be preferable for them to have an enum or a list of properties?

Comment: The string is passed into a constructor to create a new Event object, `var event = new Event(string_from_addEventListener);`, so the string is necessary to create an event

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is `string which represent the event type`.

I think internally it works like this

```
var event = new Event('click');
```

where `Event` is an event object & `click` is already a predefined event of javascript